# Laravel Mix: VueJS - Componente en Formulario HTML - Agregar atributo name

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

Un saludo, estoy trabajando con `Larevel` y gradualmente me he ido moviendo de `JQuery` a `VueJS` (a pesar de que tengo muy pero muy poca experiencia con Vue) sin embargo hoy descubrí que si tienes un `id` en una etiqueta html que sea controlada por `Vue` inactivo todo el código `JQuery`, así que tenía un `datepicker` que funcionaba con `JQuery` y se me inhabilitó porque deseaba realizar unas validaciones en `Vue`.

Ahora opté por reemplazar el `datepicker` de `jquery` por un `datepicker` de `bootstrap-vue`, ya logré que cargue la vista pero no logro que con el formulario viaje el campo de la fecha al controlador.

Lo estoy haciendo a través de `WebPack` con `Laravel Mix`, a continuación el código de mi formulario, podrán ver en la etiqueta `<form>` que tengo un id con el que controlo las validaciones del formulario (Esto no lo hago con Laravel Mix) que se llama `editSubscriberForm` y otra en el componente datepicker.

```html
<form id="editSubscriberForm" @submit="checkForm" class="user" method="POST" action="/edit_subscriber/{{$email->subscriberemail_id}}" autocomplete="off">
  @csrf
  <div v-if="errors.length" class="alert alert-danger mt-4">
    <b style="color: red">Please correct the following error(s):</b>
    <li v-for="error in errors">@{{ error }}</li>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email"><strong>Email</strong></label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="{{ $email->subscriber_email }}" name="email" v-model="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name"><strong>Name</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="{{ $email->subscriber_name }}" name="name" v-model="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname"><strong>Last Name</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="{{$email->subscriber_lastname}}" name="lastname" v-model="lastname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
      <label for="phone"><strong>Phone</strong></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="phone" placeholder="{{ $email->subscriber_phone }}" name="phone" v-model="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="whatsapp"><strong>WhatsApp</strong></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="whatsapp" placeholder="{{ $email->whatsapp_number }}" name="whatsapp" v-model="whatsapp">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="app">
    <label for="custom-field4"><strong>Birth Date</strong></label>
    <datepicker-vue v-model="birthDate" name="birth_date">
    </datepicker-vue>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="birth-date"><strong>Birth Date</strong></label>
                                <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="{{$email->birth_date}}"
                                    name="birth_date" v-model="birthDate">
                            </div>-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="custom-field1"><strong>Custom Field 1</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="customField1" placeholder="{{$email->custom_field1}}" name="custom_field1" v-model="customField1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="custom-field2"><strong>Custom Field 2</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="customField2" placeholder="{{$email->custom_field2}}" name="custom_field2" v-model="customField2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="custom-field3"><strong>Custom Field 3</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="customField3" placeholder="{{$email->custom_field3}}" name="custom_field3" v-model="customField3">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="custom-field4"><strong>Custom Field 4</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="customField4" placeholder="{{$email->custom_field4}}" name="custom_field4" v-model="customField4">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-user" name="submit-edituser" value="Update User"> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning btn-user" value="Clear Form">
  </div>
</form>
```

Y el componente es el que me suministra por defecto **Bootstrap Vue**:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
    <div>
        <b-form-datepicker
            v-model="value"
            :min="min"
            :max="max"
            locale="en"
        ></b-form-datepicker>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        const now = new Date();
        const today = new Date(
            now.getFullYear(),
            now.getMonth(),
            now.getDate()
        );
        // 15th two months prior
        const minDate = new Date(today);
        minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - 2);
        minDate.setDate(15);
        // 15th in two months
        const maxDate = new Date(today);
        maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + 2);
        maxDate.setDate(15);

        return {
            value: "",
            min: minDate,
            max: maxDate
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Ahora no se si quiera si se puede hacer, pero quiero agregar el atributo name a la etiqueta `<datepicker-vue></datepicker-vue>` para poder enviarlo en dicho formulario. De no poderse hacer, que solución me recomiendan para resolver el problema con datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Logré resolver pasar el atributo name declarando el atributo en el componente de la siguiente forma:

Declare el props con el nombre name

```html
export default {
  data() {
    const now = new Date();
    const today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
    // 15th two months prior
    const minDate = new Date(today);
    minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - 2);
    minDate.setDate(15);
    // 15th in two months
    const maxDate = new Date(today);
    maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + 2);
    maxDate.setDate(15);

    return {
      value: "",
      min: minDate,
      max: maxDate,
      name: "birthDate",
    };
  },
  props: {
    name: String,
  },
};
```

En el `return` coloqué un dato declaratorio y lo pasé al template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-datepicker v-model="value" :min="min" :max="max" locale="en" :name="name"></b-form-datepicker>
  </div>
</template>
```

Ahora en la plantilla blade llamo mi componente pasandole el nombre con el que espero recibirlo en el  controlador y listo:

```html
<div class="form-group" id="app">
  <label for="custom-field4"><strong>Birth Date</strong></label>
  <datepicker-vue v-model="birthDate" name="birth_date">
  </datepicker-vue>
</div>
```